# Why does this macro result in an unresolved name error?

Tags: macros, rust

I would like to compile code similiar to this minimal test case:

```
macro_rules! why {
    ( [ $saved:ident ] $body:block ) => {
        let $saved = 3;
        $body
        let _a = $saved;
    }
}

fn bar() {
    why!([saved] {
    });
}

fn main() {
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
src/main.rs:10:20: 10:21 error: unresolved name `saved` [E0425]
src/main.rs:10         why!([saved] {
                                  ^
src/main.rs:10:9: 11:12 note: in this expansion of why! (defined in src/main.rs)
src/main.rs:10:20: 10:21 help: run `rustc --explain E0425` to see a detailed explanation
```

Other macros that introduce variables work; what's the problem here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `macro_rules!` is kinda broken when it comes to macros that expand to statements.

The problem is basically that it considers each statement *independently* for the purposes of hygiene.  In other words, the third statement literally *cannot see* the binding defined on the first line.

In some cases, you can work around this by wrapping the statements in a block:

```
macro_rules! why {
    ( [ $saved:ident ] $body:block ) => {
        {
            let $saved = 3;
            $body
            let _a = $saved;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That solves it and makes me understand the problem. (I do not want to write, that it makes sense :))

Answer (score 1):

Your `fn bar` doesn't have anything named `saved` in scope at the invocation site.

Comment: When I introduce a line `let saved = 3` in bar() before the macro, it compiles, even though te saved inside the macro block has nothing to do with the one outside (except for shadowing it).

Comment: That's right. Rust's macros are [_hygienic_](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/macros.html#hygiene). One of the repercussions of macro hygiene is the inability to introduce variables like that into the calling scope. You _can_ return values, however.

Comment: This is not entirely true, as your link says: "This holds for let bindings and loop labels, but not for items. So the following code does compile:". See for example https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lazy-static.rs .